# Retrieving the Subject executing a java.security.PrivilegedAction at runtime

Tags: java, authorization, jaas

I am trying to retrieve the Subject that is currently executing a Privileged Action under the JAAS framework, in order to be able to extract its principals. Basically, I need to verify at run-time that the Privileged Action is indeed executed by the principal that has the right to do so.

Or, to put it differently: is it possible to get the current LoginContext at run-time as some kind of system property (and not by creating a new one)? This would easily allow extracting the Subject.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you need the LoginContext?

If you just need the Subject (with all attached Principals), you can do

```
 Subject activeSubject = Subject.getSubject(AccessController.getContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to manage such a mechanism yourself. For instance if this is a web application where you authenticate once and then associate the authentication with a session. You store the `LoginContext` in the session. One trick to make it available in other parts of the code would be to make a thread local wrapper that you set/unset at the start/end of every thread invocation (such as a request).

```
public class LoginContextHolder {

    private static ThreadLocal<LoginContext> ctx = new ThreadLocal<LoginContext>();

    public static void set(LoginContext lc) {
        ctx.set(lc);
    }

    public static LoginContext get() {
        return ctx.get();
    }

}


public class LoginContextFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {

       LoginContext ctx = null;
       HttpSession sess = (HttpSession)((HttpRequest)request).getSession(false);
       if (sess != null) {
          ctx = (LoginContext)sess.getAttribute("ctx");
       }

       try {
         LoginContextHolder.set(ctx);
          chain.doFilter(request, response);
       } finally {
         LoginContextHolder.set(null);
       }

    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, I was also starting to think that this is something i have to do myself. It is a bit surprising though.

Comment: I suspect they leave that aspect completely to the user. The semantics for when to create a LoginContext is completely app specific - it's very different to have a X.509 SSL-certificate auth, which would happen every socket reconnect to a username/password login page.